# codeigniter set time click button NOW() func

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on a CI project, quite newbie guys, I have this table with three columns and the last column is a button. What I'd like this button to do is save the current time & date. In mysql I have `time_sign` table with columns: `time-in` and `time-out` (both are `timestamp`). Please help me with this one. Need to figure out how to save `timestamp` with this button.

**In my view: (table_view.php)**

```
<?php
     foreach ($users as $user): ?>
     <tr>
        <td><?=$user->name;?></td>
        <td><?=$user->position;?></td>
        <td width="100px">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>tabledisplay/recTime">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="time-in">Sign In</button>
            </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**In my controller: (tabledisplay.php)**

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->view('loginview.php');
    $this->load->model('table_model/display_table');      
}

function recTime()
{
    $this->load->model('table_model/recordTime');      
}
```

**In my model: (table_model.php)**

```
function display_table()
{
    $this->db->where('username', $this->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', md5($this->post('password')));
    $this->db->get('users');
    iif ($query->(num_rows==1){ return TRUE;})
}

function recordTime()
{
    $this->db->set('time-in', 'NOW()', FALSE);
    $this->db->insert('time_sign', $data);
}
```

When I click the button the URL on the browser becomes:

*http://[::1]/usc3/index.php/**tabledisplay/index.php***

Wasn't it supposed to perform recTime function in tabledisplay controller?

Thank you..

Comment: remove type="submit" from your button. Its submitting your page.

Comment: removed type but no changes @DaveL